# How to write current thread task continuation that will execute after standard continuation worked?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I need to write extension method which will work like `Task.ContinueWith()` but on main thread and after `Task.ContinueWith()` ended.

```
public static Task ContinueWithOnMainThread(this Task task, Action action) {
    return task.ContinueWith(t => action(), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

This method works but its executing before Task.ContinueWith()

That's how I tested it:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += delegate {
            LogThread("\nInMain ThredId: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            var task = new Task(InTask);
            task.ContinueWith(TaskContinue);
            task.ContinueWithOnMainThread(ReturnedToMainThread);
            task.Start();
        };
    }

    void InTask() {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, (Action<string>)LogThread, "\nInTask ThredId: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    void TaskContinue(Task task) {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, (Action<string>)LogThread, "\nTaskContinue ThredId: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    void ReturnedToMainThread() {
        LogThread("\nReturnedToMainThread ThredId: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }

    void LogThread(string text) {
        TB.Text += text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried _anything_? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Your situation is *really* unclear - you've given us no indication how you're using this, or how you're diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Now my situtation is clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue is right here:

```
var task = new Task(InTask);
task.ContinueWith(TaskContinue);
task.ContinueWithOnMainThread(ReturnedToMainThread);
```

You're adding both continuations to the same `task`.  If you want `ReturnedToMainThread` to run after `TaskContinue` then you need the continuation running `TaskContinue` to be what you pass to `ContinueWithOnMainThread`.  You could do this like so:

```
var task = new Task(InTask);
task.ContinueWith(TaskContinue)
.ContinueWithOnMainThread(ReturnedToMainThread);
```

It's also worth noting that `ContinueWithOnMainThread` won't always run the continuation on the main thread.  It will run the continuation from the context that was active when the continuation was added.  If you add the continuation from the main thread (even if the task it is being run after isn't in the main thread) then you're fine, but if you actually attach the continuation from a background thread/context then it will run in that background context.